# How to store intermediate results from LINQ query to DB and avoid client evaluation or running partial queries few times

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a LINQ query:

```
var firstOrDeFault = context.ADbSet
     .Where(a => a.Id == uniqueId) //1 record matching, I want to store it somewhere
     .SelectMany(a => a.b) 
     .Where(b=> b.c.Select(x => x.ListProperty.Id).Contains(otherUniqueId)) //1 record matching, I want to store it somewhere
     .FirstOrDefault(); //this is stored in the variable I assign to
```

The thing is I would like to gather intermediate results that I indicated in the comments, but by doing I want to avoid:

- client evaluation of queries on those intermediate results
- traversing records few times because I stored the intermediate results (naively I could run parts of the query separately, but this is wasting time)

by doing so not cause client execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query. I hope unique Ids are really unique.

```cs
var query = 
    from a in context.ADbSet
    where a.Id == uniqueId
    from b in a.b
    from c in b.c
    where c.ListProperty.Id == otherUniqueId
    select new 
    {
        a,
        c
    };

var first = query.First();
var a = first.a;
var c = first.c;
```

Comment: Sorry for being so fussy brat, but is it possible with standard lambda format?

Comment: Query syntax is just syntax sugar over Lambda syntax. So yes it is possible. But readability and maintainability in lambda syntax goes down when you use several tables in query.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try thay tomorrow morning.

Comment: One more thing how to `Include(c => c.ListProperty)` in this style I purposefully omitted it because I didn't expect LINQ style.

Comment: Just use `Include`, you can mix lambda syntax with query syntax.

Comment: I have no idea why `from` works as `Select` and `SelectMany` at the same time, but it somehow works.

Comment: `from + from`. Second and others `from` are `SelectMany`. If you have `Resharper` or `Rider`, you can convert query syntax to lambda by single click. But believe me it will be super ugly.